How to generate a list of abbreviations that gets generated in the frontmatter?
How would I edit the .cls file for this project (https://github.com/bardsoftware/template-thes-pu/tree/master) to generate a list of abbreviations in the front matter, similar to how the list of figures gets generated?

You shouldn't be editing a class file to produce a list of abbreviations, you should be able to do it all in the tex file. Do any of How to generate list of abbreviations in LaTeX?,  How to create both list of abbreviations and list of nomenclature using nomencl package?, Best solution for acronyms, abbreviations, glossary and index help?
